# How activate gestures on Android to toggle Drawer Navigator of React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a Drawer Navigation with React Navigation, but the gestures (swipe left/right), to open/close the Drawer, don't work.

Its running on a Asus 4 Max with Android 8.1. The project uses:

- React Native@0.59.1
- React@16.8.3
- React Navigation@3.5.1
- React Native Gesture Handler@1.1.0

I already trying to change the Lock Mode of the drawer.

If i use a Button with `this.props.navigation.openDrawer()` or `this.props.navigation.closeDrawer()` it works.

I thought that could be the Gesture Handler, but when I create a Tab Navigator the Swipe works pretty well.

My routes file:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Main from './pages/Main';
import Plans from './pages/Plans'

const DrawerRoutes = createDrawerNavigator({
    Main,
    Plans
})

const StackRoutes = createStackNavigator({
    Login,
    App: DrawerRoutes
});

const RoutesContainer = createAppContainer(StackRoutes)

export default RoutesContainer;
```

I expect to be able to swipe from left to right to open, and the inverse to close the Drawer.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    swipeEnabled: true,
}
```

use swipe enabled